# Create indicator from two groups

Tags: r, categories

I have this data frame:

```
df<- data.frame(j = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
                t = c(2000,2010,2000,2010,2000,2010))
> df
        j    t
1       a 2000
2       a 2010
3       b 2000
4       b 2010
5       c 2000
6       c 2010
```

I am trying to create an indicator `jt` to identify the country/year:

```
        j    t  jt
1       a 2000  1
2       a 2010  2
3       b 2000  3
4       b 2010  4
5       c 2000  5
6       c 2010  6
7       c 2010  6
8       c 2010  6
```

The last two observations signal that I can have multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df<- data.frame(j = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
                t = c(2000,2010,2000,2010,2000,2010,2010,2010))
df$jt <- paste(df$j, df$t, sep="")
df$jt <- as.factor(df$jt)
str(df)
```

That makes `jt` a factor with levels for each unique combination. If you really want them to be numeric, you can coerce them using the factor levels:

```
df$jt <- as.numeric(factor(df$jt, levels = unique(df$jt)))
df
```

Comment: Works. I prefer this base R solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `paste` the rows of 'df', and get the numeric index by `match`ing 'v1' with the `unique` values.

```
 v1 <- do.call(paste0, df)
 df$jt <- match(v1, unique(v1))
```

---

Or we can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'j' and 't', we get the `.GRP` and assign (`:=`) it to 'jt'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, jt := .GRP ,.(j, t)]
df
#   j    t jt
#1: a 2000  1
#2: a 2010  2
#3: b 2000  3
#4: b 2010  4
#5: c 2000  5
#6: c 2010  6
#7: c 2010  6
#8: c 2010  6
```